# Can't get data from .pipe(map())

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, nestjs

Got some problems with observable.
I have a function, with one returns me an Observable.

```
public getData(userId) {
    const data = this.execute({userId: userId});
    return {event: "data.get", data: data}
}

private execute(input: SomeDto):  Observable<SomeRefType[]> {
    return this.databaseGateway.queryMany(DatabaseCommand.WebRecordGetbyparticipantid, {
      parameters: {
        prm_contextuserid: input.userId,
        prm_filterparticipantids: null,
        prm_filtertext: null
      }
    }).pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

[Type what pipe(map) returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8p7S.png)

[What I'm got when trying to return or log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hcgi.png)

**Question**: Why .pipe(map(res => res)) don't work? What am I doing wrong?

For sure, I can read data from .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => console.log(data)), but, how can I return data from construction like this?

Thanks everyone! Have a good day!

Comment: `map(res => res)` - this contstuction DOES NOTHING - jsut remove this

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [Rxjs documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) observable are *lazy computation*.

It means the as long as you don't subscribe to them they won't do anything. It exists two ways to trigger a subscription.

Either within a ts file using `.susbcribe()` or within a view when calling an endpoint.

If you're using nestjs it would be when calling the url defined within a `@Controller('')` with an http verb like `@Get('path')`

By convention you suffix observable variables with $: `data$ = new Observable<any>()`.

Comment: there no UI, looks like man is building an API

Comment: My bad, I changed the asnwer accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

At some point you'll have to convert the observable to a promise.  Best to do it early and convert it using **firstValueFrom** immediately after the query.
Then convert your caller to an async method to use the returned value.

```
public async getData(userId): Promise<{ event: string, data: SomeRefType[] }> {
  const data = await this.execute({userId: userId});
  return { event: 'data.get', data };
}

private execute(input: SomeDto):  Promise<SomeRefType[]> {
  const res$ = this.databaseGateway.queryMany(DatabaseCommand.WebRecordGetbyparticipantid, {
    parameters: {
      prm_contextuserid: input.userId,
      prm_filterparticipantids: null,
      prm_filtertext: null
    }
  });
  return firstValueFrom(res$);
}
```